# What do you call the first item in Navigator area of Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, navigator

When communicating with other people you often have to refer to the first blue (root) item of the Project Navigators Content Area (see image below, in this case that item has the name Adventure).

Is there any official name for this item? If not how do you refer to it? Some people refer to it as the "The blue project file icon in the Project navigator", but is there not a better or more succinct name?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is called the Project navigator.

[image: lorem]

Comment: According to Apple the Project Navigator is the whole area, including the Navigation bar, Content area and Filter bar. I am looking for a name for the "Project file in the Project navigator", not the name of the whole Project Navigator..

Comment: I think you could just safely call it the project.  Because that the project navigator can house many projects.  So if you use cocoa pods there would be a separate item in there called Pods as it's own project.  So i think you can call it the the project navigator or just the project and people would know what you were talking about.